# When trying to zip up and compress multiple files, how do you zip using InputStream and return as InputStream?

Tags: java, io, zip

I have an excel file that I want to send as an attachment in email as well as a couple other text files, but I want to zip those files for size reasons.  How would I go about this using InputStream and returning as InputStream?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `ZipInputStream`?

Comment: @hoaz I haven't yet.  I'm unsure of which way to go with this due to being new to Java, especially new to this so I'm a little lost at this point in where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to create Zip File.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipFileTest
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try{

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\MyFile.zip");
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry("spy.log");
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\spy.log");

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            zos.closeEntry();

            //remember close it
            zos.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        }catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this pose as a good model for future files that may need to be compressed into the zip file?  I'm counting on this being a robust program, and when implemented, am looking for the best way possible for a model that makes it easier to just simply make a new instance when wanting to include another file in the future.